# BigQuery SQL syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got end of script at [9:2]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new and not sure what I am doing wrong  I am trying to create a temp file and I am getting a syntax error with the following query:

```
WITH trees_temp AS
(
    SELECT *   
    FROM
        (SELECT *
         FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_1995
        JOIN bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_2005
             ON tree_census_1995.diameter = tree_census_2005.tree_dbh
        WHERE diameter > 30)
)
```

Comment: You have a CTE but no `SELECT`.

Comment: oh sorry Im learning I thought the SELECT after the WITH is what it needed?  Sorry

Comment: . . The `SELECT` is used to define the *CTE*.  Then there should be another `SELECT` that uses the CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a [common table expression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause) - meaning that temporary table (trees_temp) is only available in the query you're running. You'll need to follow your WITH statement with a SELECT statement to actually query it.

```
WITH trees_temp AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_1995
 JOIN bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_2005
    ON tree_census_1995.diameter = tree_census_2005.tree_dbh
 WHERE diameter > 30
)
SELECT * FROM trees_temp;
```

If you want to create a temporary table that can be used across different queries you can create a new [table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) or a [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) and give it an expiration time. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my-dataset.trees_temp
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2021-04-15 00:00:00 UTC"
)
as 
(
 SELECT t95.*
 FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_1995 as t95
 JOIN bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_2005 as t05
    ON t95.diameter = t05.tree_dbh
 WHERE diameter > 30
)
```

Comment: thank you so much Leigha and for the link!!  that helped so much!